# Storage for save object class nodejs

Tags: node.js

Can I save/store objects from class to storage like firebase or anything?
In my case I have some arrays, lets define them like this

```
arr = [new Class(1), new Class(2), new Class(3)]
```

when am restart the script, then my data in variable arr has gone, right?
someone can help to save these arrays, which restart the script then I no need recalling the new class

Comment: No. There is no *good* way to serialize a Javascript class and persist it like you can with POJOs. If you really want to, like beyond all point of reason, performance, or safety, you can write a custom `toString` method that prints out what you need as a string, store the string wherever, then `eval` it back (N.B. don't actually do that).

Comment: I see, thanks sir for your explain, have a nice day :)